# Action to use Battle Healing?

Tags: l5r, l5r-4e

Given the text below, my question is: what type of action is it to use this ability (free, simple, complex)? There's a pre-campaign disagreement about this.

> #### NEW ADVANTAGE: BATTLE HEALING
>
> [MYSTICAL] (5 POINTS)
> Some of the most ardent and militant shugenja of the Empire, including the Kuni family and Bishamon’s Chosen among the Kitsu, understand that the essence of all Elements can be used to suffuse the broken flesh of an honorable warrior and make it whole. Water is superior for such things, of course, but the other Elements can suffice when necessary. Once per day per person, you may expend one Water spell slot or two spell slots in any other Element(s) to heal one Wound Rank of a Rokugani you are touching.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Which book is this found in?

Answer (score 2):

I can find no official ruling for this, even the errata just says the [mystical] tag should read [spiritual]. As such it's up to your GM.

Short Answer: I would default to Complex as that seems to be the standard.

Longer Answer
Assuming you use the standard [Earth*2] to calculate Wound Ranks it's healing ~10% of your max wounds, a feat that many shugenja will struggle to consistently match with Path to Inner Peace out of Character Creation (depending on caster's School and Water Ring it's effectively 3k2 to 6k4  VS TN 14-18 depending on Target's Earth Ring). It's not huge but it's nothing to scoff at either.

Shugenja Techniques and abilities that expends Spell Slots to create independent effects (not just adding dice to another roll) typically use Complex actions or longer, though exceptions exist. I assume Battle Healing was meant to fall in line with these.

I might consider allowing it to be a Simple Action, especially in a combat focused game where I don't plan to pull my punches.

Making it free just turns it into the Healing Word spell from D&D, I'll leave if that is a good or bad thing to you and your GM.

Answer (score 1):

Since the action requires the use of one or more spell slots, and isn't more specific, I would have to rule it as casting a spell, therefore **a Complex Action**. The advantage is found with the Shugenja resources in Book of Water, leading the section on pg178. Since it's not a Kata or a Kiho related item, a Simple Action is out of the question. You're effectively "taking ten" (to use d20 parlance) on Path to Inner Peace. You automatically succeed for a fixed healing amount, so timing it like a mastery level one spell seems the most appropriate.